# Не удается взаимодействовать с реестром

Tags: c#, uwp, реестр

```
RegistryKey currentUserKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey Key = currentUserKey.OpenSubKey("Key");
```

на второй строке возникает ошибка `System.Security.SecurityException: "Requested registry access is not allowed."`

Когда я делал то же самое в WinForms все работало нормально, но на UWP оно отказывается что-либо делать с реестром.

Comment: Первая ссылка по запросу `c# uwp registry` дает сразу [ответ сотрудника MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/285798/how-can-i-edit-the-registry-with-c-uwp.html), в котором прямым текстом сказано "вы не можете это сделать в UWP напрямую, только фоновый win32 процесс, запущенный как runFullTrust". Если еще поискать, то найдете даже [пример](https://github.com/PaulaScholz/RegistryUWP) того, как это сделать "в обход".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо, у меня было предположение что в UWP это делать напрямую запрещено, просто я не смог найти этому подтверждения.